# Como sumar un array en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Quiero sumar el precio de los items de un array que inicia con un array vacio y que se va llenando con una funcion.

este es el estado inicial del array.

```
 const [ticket, setTicket] = useState([]);
```

esta es la funcion que consigue el item

```
const handleGetitem = (e) => {
 setGetitem([
  {
    name: e.target.dataset.name,
    category: e.target.dataset.category,
    price: e.target.dataset.price,
  },
]);
setModalShow(true);
```

};

esta es la funcion que agrega el item a ticket

```
const handleTicket = (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   setTicket([...ticket, getItem]);
   setModalShow(false);
 };
```

esta el la funcion que trato de tener la suma

```
 const price = ticket.map((tickets) => tickets[0].price);
 const sum = price.reduce((a, b) => a + b,0);
 console.log(sum);

 30151520
```

Pero solo recibo por console este resultado

por lo que pude ver el recibe el valor que tiene que sumar solo que el algún motivo no porque no suma lo valore solo lo agrega

Comment: creo que no tiene mucho que ver react en su pregunta

Comment: puedo que tenga razon pero fue una forma de dicir

Comment: Porque tienes +a, +b, 0?, +a es redundante y el 0 no deberia estar ahi ni la coma tampoco.

Comment: Digo +a es redundante en el sentido de que puedes escribir solamente a,  puesto que es el primer valor de izquierda a derecha...

Comment: lo es provado sin el +a i tampoco funciona i el 0 esta ay para dar un valor inicial al array ya que si no tiene valor inicial lansa un error

Comment: has intentado `const price = ticket.map((tickets) => Number(tickets[0].price));` para que convierta el precio de string a numero

Comment: Muchas gracias Isaac con tu fragmento  de código pude resolver el problema esa era mi problema estaba sumando un string en vez de un numero .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás cerca pero estás errando en el map cuando en vez de devolver los precios de cada item, devuelves siempre el primero `tickets[0].price`.
Debería ser 
`const price = tickets.map((ticket) => ticket.price);` 
Y por ende `const [tickets, setTickets] = useState([]);` ya que es una lista de tickets tienes sentido que sean plurales.

La función `reduce` la tienes bien a pesar del comentario que dice que no, no te funciona porque el dato viene mal de la función anterior.

Si necesitas sumar los precios de una lista de objetos con el campo `price`, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
const listaVacia = Array.from({ length: 10 }).fill({});

const lista = listaVacia.map(item => ({
 price: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
}));

console.log(lista);

const sumaPrecios = lista.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next.price, 0);

console.log(sumaPrecios)
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta pero lo resolvi con este código. que me parece mas un poca mas facil.      const total = tickets
                                           .map((ticket) => Number(ticket.price))
                                           .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);   mi mayor problema era que estaba suma un string solo lo converti a numero y funciono pero voy a poner tu respuesta como validad

Comment: Genial, está perfecto así también, siempre y cuando la lista no se muy grande ya que estás recorriendo la lista 2 veces, con el `.map` y luego otra vez con el `.reduce`.